# Do you use a comma after an exclamation inside quotes?

Tags: commas

Mary listens to Joe say, "Hello!", and then he leaves.

Comment: What do the quote marks, the bang, and the capital add to an indirect quotation? _Mary listens to Joe say hello, and then leaves_ says exactly the same thing and doesn't distract the reader with unnecessary punctuation. General rule: if you don't understand how a punctuation mark should be used, don't use it.

Comment: The sentence is a bit awkward - the "and" in the middle should be joining two related things, but in this case the focus of the sentence changes (from what Mary does, to what Joe does). *Mary listens to Joe say "Hello!", then watches him leave.*

Answer (score 2):

To my knowledge, if the ending punctuation in a quote is anything but a period, it *entirely* replaces the comma. Therefore, taking (a slightly modified) example, I would say:

> Mary listened as Joe exclaimed, "Oh gosh, I *love* cheese pie!" and replied, "Oh, but what about cherry pizza?"

I could be wrong, but this is what I've been taught - only if a quote originally ends in a period does it become a comma, for example:

> Joe, eyes drooping, mumbled, "I love cheese pie," and fell asleep.

where the quote itself would originally be represented as *"I love cheese pie**.**"* with a period.

Comment: Is this a bad answer? :o

Comment: I would upvote the first half but the second half (and the final suggestion) are not correct/relevant.

Comment: Then I'll go ahead and delete that.

Comment: Sweet. +1. I'm not sure who downvoted you earlier but it wasn't me.

Comment: I'm with MrHen. This is an accurate answer, and it deserves to be treated as clearing the question from the ranks of the unanswered.

Comment: @Sven Yargs I disagree; even answers that are correct (or largely considered as correct advice) do not provide suitable 'answers' on ELU if they have no authoritative (or at least, like CMoS, respected) references. // Also, elsewhere, it has been stated that 'BrE' (whatever that means) allows double punctuation for clarification. If correct, that makes this answer one style recommendation.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: The only British English style guide that I own is _The Oxford Guide to Style_ (2002). It says this about punctuation marks of unequal strength (such as an exclamation point and either a period or a comma): "When the requirements of the quoted material and that of the main sentence differ, use the stronger mark. In the examples below, the question mark supersedes the weaker full point: [Example 1:] She was heard to mutter, 'Did you do it?' [Example 2:] Can you verify that John said, 'There is only one key to the room'?" ...

Comment: ... For punctuation marks of equal strength, OGS says this: "When the terminal punctuation of the quoted material and that of the main sentence serve different functions of equal strength or importance, use both: [Example 1:] She had the nerve to ask 'Why are you here?'! [Example 2:] Did he really shout 'Stop thief!'?" These guidelines are consistent with their relevant counterparts in several U.S. English style guides, including _The Chicago Manual of Style_ (which I know you dislike). ...

Comment: ... If you can point me to a guide that offers contrary advice, I would be happy to write up an answer to the posted question here that summarizes the advice from it and from the various style guides that I have at hand. Or perhaps it would be worthwhile to write up such an answer citing only those reference books—even though their recommendations are much the same as OGS's. Please let me know if you think that would be helpful for readers of this question.

Comment: I'd not use anything but the following in running text: << Your three highlighted example quotes were carefully chosen: "Oh gosh, I love cheese pie!",  "Oh, but what about cherry pizza?", and "I love cheese pie,". >> The quotes could be rearranged to result in say < ,",>.Obviously, this need not apply where 'showing what punctuation was actually used' is not a factor. // The site I remember was not more prescriptivist  than saying << 'BrE' (a term I feel is a misnomer) allows double punctuation at the end of a quote if clarification is seen as necessary. >> // However, I'd do what Kye ...

Comment: does here, as would most people – but the fact remains that 'even answers that are correct (or largely considered as correct advice) do not provide suitable 'answers' on ELU if they have no authoritative (or at least, like CMoS, respected) references'. I can probably find a paraphrase _you_ once posted. AH: '... but this site especially prizes answers that have an identifiable basis in verifiable fact rather than just opinion. Please consider strengthening your answer by citing some independent authority that draws the same general conclusion that you do ...'.

Comment: Note that this answer was posted in spring 2014. If I recall correctly, 2014 was a transition year between the days when many highly regarded answerers at EL&U did not feel bound to cite authority for their views and the more recent period when, as you say, such citations are generally viewed as highly desirable, if not essential. I still think that my comment of May 15, 2014, was not inappropriate for the era when I posted it.

Answer (score 0):

No.  Nor would I put a comma after "say" in your sample sentence.

As constructed, there is a degree of ambiguity in the sentence.  Who is leaving after "Hello!" is said?  Mary or Joe?

Comment: As Joe leaves, he says "Hello!" to Mary. "Hello!" said Joe to Mary as he leaves. Mary see Joe leave as he says "Hello!" to her. Leaving, Joe says "Hello!" to Mary.

Comment: If Mary were leaving, wouldn't it be _she leaves_?

Comment: Generally...on occasion people have gender bent names though.